# Upload MP3 Files - Invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

Tags: ruby, postgresql, utf-8, binary, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working with the Rails 5 API (carrierWave), and i need it to put some binary data (mp3 files) in my postgres Database.

First i create a simple model like that :
`rails g scaffold Capsule name:string description:string file_upload:binary`
and then :
`rails db:migrate`
to update my database.

After that I try to do a POST with "Postman application", and using a mp3 file for my "file_upload" row.

But after that i Have a Bad Request saying that :

> {
>    "status": 400,
>    "error": "Bad Request",
>    "exception": "#sequence in UTF-8>", ...

I've searched for the problem but anything was able to help me...

How can I fix it? Thank you very much.
Best regards.

Comment: My guess is you need to specifically tell it that your file should be binary data (hey Rails, don't encode this). A little google search for 'multipart/form-data' should probably steer you in the right direction.

Comment: But i just told rails that this row is a binary data when i did "rails g scaffold Capsule name:string description:string file_upload:binary". I already search in that way, anything help me D= ...

Answer (score 0):

And mp3 is not a string it's a binary file. You can either encode it to something like uuencode or store it as bytea.

Comment: Yeah I know, my mp3 file is called file_upload, and i defined it as binary =)!

Comment: Well given that it's failing because it's not proper UTF8 the field you're storing it in is NOT binary / bytea but a text type.